# GetImage with JApplet

Tags: java, html, swing, japplet, imageicon

I have the following runnable code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main extends JApplet{
    public static Main instance;
    public static ImageIcon getImage(String fname){
        return new ImageIcon(instance.getImage(instance.getDocumentBase(),fname));
    }
    public void init(){
        instance = this;
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        JPanel p = new JPanel(){
            ImageIcon img = getImage("YES.png");
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if(img != null)
                g.drawImage(img.getImage(),0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
            }
        };
        this.setContentPane(p);
    }
}
```

When I run this in eclipse it works.  But when I run it on google chrome with the following html document:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>VResponse</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color:white;
            padding:1%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<applet code="Main.class" width="800" height="600" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following null pointer exception.:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(Unknown Source)
    at Main.getImage(Main.java:15)
    at Main$1.<init>(Main.java:21)
    at Main.init(Main.java:20)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How do I fix?

http://vickysoderlund.atspace.cc/
/---= webpage with errored japplet on it

You should beable to download the entire folder here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ng1kJkou-lcUlmWk91bEVXX28/edit?usp=sharing

And SRC code is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ng1kJkou-lYXRERWFnU1czX0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: What is the address seen in Chrome?

Comment: @MrD I don't know how to get the stack trace if the error isn't while I'm running it in eclipse.

Comment: @AndrewThompson
file:///C:/Users/Chase/Dropbox/ALL_PROJECTS/Other%20Projects/Basic/bin/index.html
Or:
http://vickysoderlund.atspace.cc/

Comment: @csga5000 Open the Java console, it will display the out put from stdout and stderr

Comment: Make sure the image is accessible from the location of html file (it should be in the same directory based on the examples)

Comment: @csga5000 checkout what [applets can and can't do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer YES.png the index.html file, and all class files are in the same director.

Comment: @MrD I looked at that, I don't see anything that says I can't load a file from the local server.

Comment: And the name is `YES.png`as opposed to `Yes.png`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I opened the java console, but it just displayed the help menu, and a random 0 on the bottom.  You guys can view the webpage I linked and look at the console yourselves if you like as well...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, it is YES.png

Comment: @MrD I added the stack trace to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with security.  When I signed the Applet, and gave it a good permissions node in the manifest it got rid of the error.

I added the following to the manifest:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *.hobogames.atspace.cc
Application-Name: GreenCube
```

I signed it in the command prompt using the following commands:

```
cd homeDirectory
keytool -genkey -alias alias -keystore .keystore

cd directoryOfJar
jarsigner jar-file alias
```

Where alias is usually your name.

This solved some security issues, and allowed me to load the image.